# Poisson Distribution fit with large counts (Python)

Tags: python, poisson-distribution, count-data, histogram

I'm trying to fit a dataset to a Poisson distribution, but have probably messed up the parameters somewhere along the way.
My data consists of 112 10 minute intervals where radiation hits a detector and is counted. Each 10 minute interval got ~1000 counts.

The issue is that after using scipy.optimize's curve_fit, I get essentially null values for all x (see picture).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.special import gammaln # x! = Gamma(x+1)
from scipy.special import factorial

############# This block is for loading data - the output, coinc, is length 112 array; [1125,1117,1056,...,1076]
df = pd.read_csv('CSMHUNT_2021-11-22_Overnight.csv',sep=';')
coinc=np.array(df[' COINC ' ][1:])
####################################################################################

def Normal(x,lamb):
    return norm.pdf(x,lamb,np.sqrt(lamb))

def Poisson(k,lamb):
    return np.exp(-lamb)*lamb**k *(1/factorial(k))

#histogram
plt.figure(dpi=100)
hist,bin_edges,params=plt.hist(coinc,bins=10,density=True,label='data')  #counts and bins

#Centres of bins
centers=(bin_edges[:-1]+bin_edges[1:])/2

#Guess for the lambda parameter. This is just the mean.
guess=np.mean(coinc)

par,cov = curve_fit(Poisson,centers,hist,p0=guess)
plt.plot(centers,Poisson(centers,*par),'r--',label='Fit')
plt.legend()
```

[image: Output plot, with fitted function zero at all values.]

I have a suspicion that I've gotten things turned around in my head, as the fit is obviously wrong somehow, but I can't spot the error.
I tried replacing the starting guess lambda=np.mean(coinc) with np.mean(hist), which produces identically zero results.

**p.s.** I am aware that for for large lambda $(\lambda>1000)$ the normal distribution with mean $\lambda$ and variance $\lambda$ is a good approximation - hence why it's also defined in my code.
It amounts to the same thing, however, as fitting to a Normal distribution still provides essentially null values (e-200 or so) for all the probabilities.

Comment: Why are you using curve fitting at all? What problem does it solve? The MLE for a Poisson is the mean, which you’ve already computed.

Comment: I don't know python, but is it possible that `curve_fit` doesn't know that it should only evaluate the function at integers? (else `factorial` will give strange results)

Comment: This histogram departs visibly from a Poisson shape (which, which this many counts, will be almost indistinguishable from a Normal distribution with a standard deviation around $33$ or so).  Yes, you do have a programming problem, but fixing that isn't on topic here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have two, non-exclusive hypotheses for the behavior.

1. Floating point arithmetic is not sufficiently precise to represent large exponents and large factorials, causing catastrophic loss of precision.
2. `curve_fit` isn't estimating the quantity that you want. There's simply no need to use the `curve_fit` function for this problem, because Poisson MLEs are easily computed.

This is fine, since we can just use the `scipy` functions for the Poisson distribution. The MLE of the Poisson parameter is the sample mean. I don't have access to your data, so I can't compute the mean, but you've already computed the mean in any event.

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gammaln

k_vals = np.array([975, 1000, 1025, 1050, 1075, 1100,1125, 1150])
guess = 1030.4
probs = poisson.pmf(k_vals, mu=guess)
```

This gives reasonable results.

```
2.80323690e-03 8.01994963e-03 1.22844824e-02 1.02289554e-02
 4.69781334e-03 1.20658551e-03 1.75611575e-04 1.46676596e-05
```

Alternatively, we can write a quick-and-dirty log-scale implementation of the Poisson pmf and then exponentiate.

```
def dirty_poisson_pmf(x, mu):
    out = -mu + x * np.log(mu) - gammaln(x + 1)
    return np.exp(out)

dirty_probs = dirty_poisson_pmf(k_vals, mu=guess)
diff = probs - dirty_probs
```

And the differences are all on the order of machine epsilon for double-precision floating point.

```
[ 1.27502175e-15 -3.64638875e-15  5.58580959e-15  4.65252836e-15
 -2.13631196e-15  5.48606299e-16 -7.98514900e-17  6.66953743e-18]
```

When I try to directly apply the formula for the Poisson PMF, I get `RuntimeWarning`s from numpy that there has been overflow. The results are NAN. So we know that hypothesis (1) is correct.

Because hypothesis (2) is not necessary to estimate a Poisson PMF, and we've already, we don't need to worry about debugging `curve_fit`.

Comment: You import `gammaln` -- that's the trick! Work on the log scale whenever you have extremely large or small positive numbers.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, because I believe I've found the (actual) issue; the "centers" list in the above is NOT a list of integers - so the factorial function defaults to zero. If I instead use something like np.arange(int(min(centers)),int(max(centers))) it is computed just fine.